Using objTo3d-tiles to create 3D tiles for cesium
I'm trying to create a 3D tileset from the pointcloud file I meshed into an OBJ file.
It looks like this:

I then run this command obj23dtiles -i "C:/Users/user/Downloads/test.obj" --tileset "C:/Users/user/Downloads/test" --outputBatchTable --b3dm
it outputs a b3dm file and a tileset.json with no errors
The tileset.json looks like this
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "0.0",
    "tilesetVersion": "1.0.0-obj23dtiles",
    "gltfUpAxis": "Y"
  },
  "geometricError": 200,
  "root": {
    "transform": [
      0.9686356343768792,
      0.24848542777253738,
      0,
      0,
      -0.15978791397834685,
      0.6228786484970693,
      0.7658263587739148,
      0,
      0.1902966903594209,
      -0.7418067008535064,
      0.6430474229845627,
      0,
      1083485.0813123332,
      -4223596.805988828,
      3636784.735333375,
      1
    ],
    "boundingVolume": {
      "region": [
        -1.2609648048324065,
        0.6988880191516715,
        -1.260813051071949,
        0.6988918085356715,
        0,
        715.625
      ]
    },
    "geometricError": 0,
    "refine": "ADD",
    "content": {
      "url": "test.b3dm"
    }
  }
}

However, when I try to view it on Cesium, the bounding box is in the wrong position and there's no sign of my obj file

What am I doing wrong?
